# 401 error with .NET Web API when using dotnet run command but not in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio-code, postman, dotnet-cli

I have been developing an application that involves using JWT validation and this is my first time doing it. Needless to say I have learned a lot and feel good about where it is currently at. However, as I had figured out one of my last issues with it I started to run into an error with one of my endpoints, 401 Unauthorized. This was actually a positive for me because now I knew the validation was working.

Once I used a valid token and put it in Postman and hit the same endpoint, still I got 401. As an important note I am working on Mac and had been doing all this work on VSCode since I figured I should get more used to that and not be so dependent on Visual Studio. I had originally started in Visual Studio using Parallels.

This is where it gets weird. I decided to pull down the new changes I had made that I thought should now be working. This was pulled into the Visual Studio local repo now and when I ran it and hit the endpoint in Postman with the same token it worked like a charm.

So my guess is that I am either using the "dotnet run" command wrong or have encountered some weird edge case. Any thoughts or help would be much appreciated.

**Side Note:**

Before anyone says anything about secrets/appsettings I did make sure all of those were the same on the VSCode and VisualStudio side so I know it is not that. If I need to post any files for more understanding I would be happy to do so.

Again all I have been doing to run the app on the VSCode (non parallels) side of things is using the "dotnet run" command.

**Code for adding auth:**

```html
public static void AddIdentityAndAuth(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        // Add Identity (DefaultTokenProviders didn't work)
        services.AddIdentityCore<FinFormUser>()
            .AddRoles<FinFormRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<FinFormDbContext>();

        var domain = $"https://{config["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]}/";

        /* New Implementation of Auth0 signature validation */
        /* Uses Auth0 supplied jwks endpoint now */
        var client = new RestClient(domain);
        var request = new RestRequest(resource:".well-known/jwks.json");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var jsonRes = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Auth0SignResponse>(response!.Content!.ToString());

        var signingKey = jsonRes!.keys[0].x5c[0]; //key from json response
        var publicKeyArray2 = Convert.FromBase64String(signingKey);
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(publicKeyArray2);
        /* End Implementation */

        // Add in Authentication with JWT
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidAudience = config["AUTH0_AUDIENCE"],
                ValidIssuer = domain,
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (t, st, i, p) => new[] {
                    new X509SecurityKey(cert) 
                },
            };
        });

        // Add Authorization
        services.AddAuthorization();
    }
```

**Running API on MacOS:**

```html
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7154
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5274
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

**Result on MacOS:**
[postman screenshot result Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXOev.png)

**Running API on Parallels (Windows):**

```html
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7154
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5274
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

**Result on Parallels:**
[postman screenshot result windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED72d.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.